# Change a variable in a coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lambda, coroutine

I'm developing an AI and I'm wanting to use a coroutine to help delay the enemies decision making.

Issue is, I can't figure out how to make my MoveZ variable change outside of the script. As soon as the functions close, it drops the value for MoveZ.

How can I make it so that way after the coroutine passed it saves the MoveZ variable for reference later within the script?

I asked on the Unity Scripting forum and they directed me to use lambda syntax, but it doesn't solve my issue.

My code calling the coroutine

```
StartCoroutine(FindRun((i)=>{MoveZ = i; Debug.Log(MoveZ);}));
```

Declaring the coroutine

```
IEnumerator FindRun(System.Action<int> callback){

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
    if (Distance > 3){
        callback(1);
    }
    else if (Distance < 2) {
        callback(-1);
    }
    else {
        Travelling = false;
    }
} // Closes FindRun
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is MoveZ declared? Please post a more complete example.

Comment: Yes, here's my complete code

Edit: I can't upload all of it , but yes MoveZ is declared. It's meant to be put into a Vector3 later on.

Comment: _"I can't upload all of it"_ -- it can be hard to post a complete code example for Unity3d issues. But you need to come a _lot_ closer to [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you have here. Please provide a more specific problem description than the ambiguous _"drops the value for MoveZ"_, and provide enough code so that we can see exactly how _all_ of the relevant variables are declared and used. Most likely the _MoveZ_ captured by your lambda is not the variable you think it is, but without a better question, there's no way to know for sure.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0vv46Z6C

I think this should work, no? Line 87 is calling the coroutine and line 123 is defining it. MoveZ is declared within the class but not within the methods, at line 33

Comment: Could it be that you're setting `MoveZ = 0;` at the top of your update function?

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't even think of that, I've been looking at examples, explanations, and reviewing my knowledge on programming, to no avail and this was why lol.